# getting image from gallery not working in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

We need get image form Gallery.So we add plugin to our app then we tried like this

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
   var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
 document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
 function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("ondevicereday");
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }
   function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    alert("Open");
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }
 function capturePhoto(){
    alert("justOpen");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });

     }
     function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
      }
```

but we are unable to open gallery.When Page loaded "`ondevicereday`" alert showing then we click on `openGallery` button it's showing `justOpen` alert but we are unable to open 
So Please guide to us and tell me what wrong in code

Comment: rename `onPhotoDataSuccess` to `onPhotoURISuccess`

Comment: @Naveen Dodda did u manage to solve?

Answer (score 0):

i have impalmented this using File API plugin of cordova ,The file API plugin would let u access the file system in your Android Phone.

Here is the link https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <button style="width:30%;" onclick="pickImage()">Clean Data</button>
                <p id="lastPhoto"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pickImage(){
                var lastPhotoContainer = document.getElementById("lastPhoto");
                var doc= document.getElementBy
                window.imagePicker.getPictures(
                function(results) {
                    console.log(results);
                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var imageUri=results[i];
                        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                        lastPhotoContainer.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageUri + "' style='width: 75%;' />";
                        }
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error);
                }
            );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this simple example takes a single image from the local storage and shows it on the screen of the app , u can go ahead and convert the image from the uri to base64 and use it as u like .Now this would populate the already taken picture into html ..Hope this helps.